# ios app store error: The binary being analyzed must be an executable

Tags: ios, app-store

I've tried to upload my app to the app store, however a few minutes after it is uploaded to the store I receive an e-mail specifying the following error:
The binary being analyzed must be an executable: /tmp/mz_414001245943525872dir/MyApp-1.ipa/Payload/MyApp.app/main.o

While preparing the app for upload I used the following guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/

The strange thing is that the app passes all the validations without a problem. The error appears only after the app is submitted to the app store

Answer (score 0):

This should usually be the case, but you should check your build settings and make sure you set the Mach-O Type for your release configuration to `Executable`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just checked and the Mach-O Type was already set to executable.